# Restoring Passwords in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, backup, passwords, cookies, username

Recent versions of Chrome have been a disaster, crashing constantly and frequently taking windows with it. I backed up everything in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data.  I uninstalled the current version of Google and installed a recent version (86.0.42...). I then copied the cookie and login data files from the backup to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.

It seems, from several posts I've read here, that this should have worked.  But it didn't.  Chrome does not know any of my user names and passwords.  What did I do wrong, and what else can I try?

Thank you

Comment: Try to disable [Hardware Acceleration](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122) in Chrome.

Comment: Is that to allow me to paste the cookie and password files, or to stop the newer versions of Chrome from their constant crashing? Thank you